# Why empheral node does not deleted from zookeeper after sessiontimeout value

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am creating an Empheral node with the help of CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient method which takes, znodes addresses,sessiontimeoutinms,connectiontimeoutinms,Retry) . I have pass 5*1000 as sessiontimeoutinms and 15*1000 as connectiontimeoutinms. This method is able to create the EPHEMERAL node in my zookeeper but this EPHEMERAL node does not deleted till the application run.

Why this happens as sessiontimeout is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is your heartbeat setting for Zookeeper (aka tickTime) is higher, and minimum session timeout can't be lower than 2*tickTime.

Answer (score 0):

to debug, when an ephemeral node is created check the ephemeralOwner from the zkCli. the value is the session id.

when the client that owns the node, in the zookeeper logs, you should get this line :

> INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2182)::PrepRequestProcessor@486] -
>   Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x161988b731d000c

in this case the ephemeralOwener was 0x161988b731d000c. If you don't get that, you would have got some error. In my case it was EOF exception, which was because of a client library and server mismatch.